# Access a JFrame's context from deep inside a Pojo

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety

**Situation**

I have the following situation in a multi window environment:

```
Main application -> JFrame 1 -> Swing Components -> Pojo 1
                 -> JFrame 2 -> Swing Components -> Pojo 2
                 -> JFrame 3 -> Swing Components -> Pojo 3
                 -> ...
```

Each JFrame has some context information, e. g. the frame id. The frames are created from within the same application.

**Question**

Is there some way (or pattern) that I can access the JFrame's context information from the Pojo classes without having to hand it over through the entire chain of components? And without having to hand over e. g. a swing component and using e. g. SwingUtilities.getRoot()?

I can't use static variables of course. A ThreadLocal might help, but that's tricky and you can't instantiate the Pojo from within e. g. an ActionListener. Maybe someone has a better idea *(other than changing the concept of frame instantiation)*?

Comment: 1. Why is that context stored on a view component, and not somewhere on a back-end/model class ? 2. At some point, the Pojo gets added to the frame. Isn't there an option to pass the necessary context info or pointers to the Pojo class ?

Comment: Simple Example: The JFrame stores the current timezone as data, each frame has a different time zone. The panels inside each JFrame can vary depending on user decisions. So the common place is the frame, it holds some data structure with the timezone. As a very basic example I have a calendar which has a pojo which needs the timezone for whatever reason. Of course I can have the calendar pick the timezone from the frame and hand it over. But in the end there could be a long chain of components and objects, so a more direct approach with access to the frame data would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest design is to encapsulate the required context information into a single root class (this can be as simple or as complex as you like, e.g. a `Properties` object, a single custom bean, a full model package) and then pass that class down through the chain. Each of the swing components in the chain would need to be a subclass of a `javax.swing` class so as to allow constructors which include the context information parameter. The overhead of an extra field and an extra constructor parameter in each of the classes in the chain is minimal.

Another approach is to flatten out the chain such that the `JFrame` class is responsible for creating its entire layout. It would create the Pojo object itself (plus all components in between) and thus be able to easily pass in the required context information.